# How to get the string-type content of the XML element (SimpleXMLElement), that is parsed by PHP simplexml_load_string?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the PHP 8 code:

```
$test = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FDL>
            <TITLE>
                <Title>Test element</Title>
            </TITLE>  
        </FDL>';
    $test_obj = simplexml_load_string($test);
    var_dump($test_obj->TITLE->Title);
    var_dump($test_obj->TITLE->Title->children);
```

Which returns:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    [
        0
    ]=>
  string(12) "Test element"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {}
```

And that is my problem - the `$test_obj->TITLE->Title` and `$test_obj->TITLE->Title->children` return objects (SimpleXMLElement), but I am interested in the string-type content of this element? How can I access it? Of course, if I am using echo (instead of var_dump) in my previous code then I can see the string type content, but under the cover - this is not string type variable and it does not behave as string type variable in the further PHP code where I am trying to use it.

So - how to the the string type content from the SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: A simple cast usually does the trick already. `var_dump( (string)$test_obj->TITLE->Title );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to ["cast" the variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to a string, using the standard PHP syntax `(string)$someVariableOrExpression`, which [is defined specially on the SimpleXMLElement class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php):

```php
    $test = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FDL>
            <TITLE>
                <Title>Test element</Title>
            </TITLE>  
        </FDL>';
    $test_obj = simplexml_load_string($test);
    $content = (string)$test_obj->TITLE->Title;
    var_dump($content);
    # string(12) "Test element"
```

This is actually what lets `echo` work under the hood: it first converts whatever arguments you give it to strings, which tells the SimpleXMLElement object to return its string content.

This is also shown in [some of the SimpleXML examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score -1):

You could use xpath instead of dot notation:

```
$target = (string)$test_obj->xpath("//TITLE/Title")[0];
echo $target,": ", gettype($target);
```

Output:

```
Test element: string
```

Comment: Downvoted for being completely irrelevant to the question, which is accessing the elements just fine.